# d3.js change array data mapping from normalized to regular stacked chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm able to create a normalized stacked bar chart and a regular stacked bar chart.  I would like to be able to transition between both based on a user's selection.

I've created a function to map my data to a normal distribution with the following code:

```
        function dataMapNormalize(data) {
        /*
         http://jsfiddle.net/dB96T/4/
         manually create data points for stacked bar chart with y0 values
         */

         data = data.map(function (d, i) {
            console.log("length:" + d.length);
            var j,
                columnTotal = 0,
                y0 = 0;
            for (j = 0; j < d.length; j++) {
                columnTotal += d[j].value;
            }

            for (j = 0; j < d.length; j++) {
                var y = d[j].value / columnTotal;
                d[j] = {x: i, y: y, y0: y0};
                y0 += y;
            }
            return d;
        });
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

        y = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, 1])
            .range([height, 0]);

        x = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .rangeRoundBands([100, width], .05)
            .domain(data.map(function (d) {
                return d[0].x
            }));
    }

dataMapNormalize(ond);
```

This function permanently changes my array "ond" to an array of rectangle coordinates, which is great... except when I want to show a non-normalized stacked bar chart.  If I try to pass ond to the function below, I'll get NAN.

```
function dataMapStack(data) {

        var stackTotals  = new Array();

        data = data.map(function (d, i) {
            var j,
                columnTotal = 0,
                y0 = 0;
            for (j = 0; j < d.length; j++) {
                columnTotal += d[j].value;
            }
            stackTotals.push(columnTotal);
            for (j = 0; j < d.length; j++) {
                var y = d[j].value;
                d[j] = {x: i, y: y, y0: y0};
                y0 += y;
            }
            return d;
        });

        y = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(stackTotals)])
            .range([height, 0]);

        x = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .rangeRoundBands([100, width], .05)
            .domain(data.map(function (d) {
                return d[0].x
            }));
    }
```

I'm sure there is a more graceful way of approaching this problem.  Open for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  I simply added more elements to my data.map function so that the array now has yp (percentage/normalized) and y (regular stack) values. (duh!)  I'll most likely move the x/y scale out of the function.  This was a big help: http://bl.ocks.org/tmaybe/6144082

```
function dataMap(data) {
        /*
         http://jsfiddle.net/dB96T/4/

         create rectangle dimensions for stacked bar chart

         yp = y percentage/normalized
         y = regular stack
         */

         data = data.map(function (d, i) {
            console.log("length:" + d.length);
            var j,
                columnTotal = 0,
                yp0 = 0,
                y0 = 0;

            // Count total of each stack
            for (j = 0; j < d.length; j++) {
                columnTotal += d[j].value;
            }

            for (j = 0; j < d.length; j++) {
                var y = d[j].value;
                var yp = d[j].value / columnTotal;
                d[j] = {x: i, yp: yp, yp0: yp0, y:y, y0:y0};
                yp0 += yp;
                y0 +=y;
            }
            return d;
        });
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

        y = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, 1])
            .range([height, 0]);

        x = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .rangeRoundBands([100, width], .05)
            .domain(data.map(function (d) {
                return d[0].x
            }));
    }
```